# Merge 2 JSON Strings into one by different keys in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to combine 2 JSON objects from an API with 2 different id keys.
I have tried some code in php based on my working code in react native(javascript) but rebuilding the code did not work as expected.

sample first JSON:

```
[{
    poiNumberWinter: null,
    minAge: null,
    maxAge: null,
    minSize: 100,
    maxSize: null,
    minSizeEscort: 1,
    id: 1,
    titleImageId: 390,
    titleImageWinterId: null,
    createdAt: "2018-03-14T15:45:47.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-03-26T10:58:44.000Z",
    _titleWinter: null
}]
```

sample second JSON:

```
[{
    open: false,
    poiId: "1",
    closing: null,
    opening: "2019-08-15 10:00:00",
    showTimes: null,
    waitTime: null,
    updatedAt: "2019-08-15T20:12:40.000Z",
}]
```

This is what I have tried:

```php
$rideTimesconverted = json_decode($rideTimes);
$metaDataConverted = json_decode($metaData);
$fullRideData = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rideTimesconverted); $i++) {
   $test = array_filter($metaDataConverted, function ($item) use (
     $i,
     $rideTimesconverted
   ) {
      return $item['id'] === (int) $rideTimesconverted[$i]['poiId'];
   });
      array_push($fullRideData, $rideTimesconverted[$i], $test);
}
```

based on my React Native code which works perfectly:

```
let rideTimes = await GetApiData.getRidesTime();
let rideMetaData = await GetApiData.getRidesMetaData();
let fullRideData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.rideTimes.length; i++) {
        fullRideData.push({
           ...this.state.rideTimes[i],
           ...this.state.rideMetaData.find(
              itmInner =>
                  itmInner.id ===
                      parseInt(this.state.rideTimes[i].poiId)
              )
        });
    }
```

But the results get mixed up really weird:

```
{
open: false,
poiId: "1",
closing: null,
opening: "2019-08-15 10:00:00",
showTimes: null,
waitTime: null,
createdAt: "2019-08-15T22:18:03.000Z",
updatedRow: "2019-08-15T22:18:03.000Z"
},
  [
    {
        poiNumberWinter: null,
        minAge: null,
        maxAge: null,
        minSize: 100,
        maxSize: null,
        minSizeEscort: 1,
        id: 1,
        titleImageId: 390,
        titleImageWinterId: null,
        createdAt: "2018-03-14T15:45:47.000Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-03-26T10:58:44.000Z",
        _titleWinter: null
    }
],
```

I want this result, merged on poiId and id being the same:

```
[{
    open: false,
    poiId: "1",
    closing: null,
    opening: "2019-08-15 10:00:00",
    showTimes: null,
    waitTime: null,
    createdAt: "2019-08-15T22:18:03.000Z",
    updatedRow: "2019-08-15T22:18:03.000Z"
    poiNumberWinter: null,
    minAge: null,
    maxAge: null,
    minSize: 100,
    maxSize: null,
    minSizeEscort: 1,
    id: 1,
    titleImageId: 390,
    titleImageWinterId: null,
    createdAt: "2018-03-14T15:45:47.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-03-26T10:58:44.000Z",
    _titleWinter: null
}]
```

Comment: I did not understand what is the final result you wanna achieve

Comment: I want the 2 JSON objects combined within eachother based on poiId(in the second) and id (in the first). metaData.id ===
                      parseInt(rideTimes.poiId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do the job if I read your question correctly.

```
$rideTimes = '[{
    "poiNumberWinter": null,
    "minAge": null,
    "maxAge": null,
    "minSize": 100,
    "maxSize": null,
    "minSizeEscort": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "titleImageId": 390,
    "titleImageWinterId": null,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-14T15:45:47.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-03-26T10:58:44.000Z",
    "_titleWinter": null
},
{
    "poiNumberWinter": null,
    "minAge": null,
    "maxAge": null,
    "minSize": 100,
    "maxSize": null,
    "minSizeEscort": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "titleImageId": 390,
    "titleImageWinterId": null,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-14T15:45:47.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-03-26T10:58:44.000Z",
    "_titleWinter": null
}]';

$metaData = '[{
    "open": false,
    "poiId": "1",
    "closing": null,
    "opening": "2019-08-15 10:00:00",
    "showTimes": null,
    "waitTime": null,
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:12:40.000Z"
},
{
    "open": false,
    "poiId": "2",
    "closing": null,
    "opening": "2019-08-15 15:00:00",
    "showTimes": null,
    "waitTime": null,
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:12:40.000Z"
}]';

function someFancyName($arrRideTime, $arrMetaData)
{
    $hits = [];
    foreach ($arrRideTime as $rTime) {
        foreach ($arrMetaData as $mData) {
            if ($mData['poiId'] == $rTime['id']) {
                $hits[] = array_merge($rTime, $mData);
            }
        }
    }
    return $hits;
}

$arrRideTime = json_decode($rideTimes, true);
$arrMetaData = json_decode($metaData, true);
echo '<pre><code>';
var_dump(someFancyName($arrRideTime, $arrMetaData));
echo '</code></pre>';
```